# python: dot separated versions comparizon

Tags: python

I`m writing a script, where i need to compare  versions of binnaries , so for example  i need to get 10.2.3   greater than 10.1.30 . If i  remove dots, i will get 1023 and 10130, which  twists my comparison upside down.

```
10.2.3 > 10.1.30  ==  1023 !> 10130
```

Till now, the only solution i came out is :

```
1. do split(".") on version number 
2. for each elemet of list i got, check  if len() is eq 1 , add one zero from  the left.
3. glue all  elements together and get  int (10.1.30 will became 100130).
4. process second version number same way and compare both as regular ints.
```

This way :

```
10.2.3 > 10.1.30  ==  100203 > 100130
```

Is this the only way to compare versions or  there are others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can borrow the code that `distutils` and its successors use to compare version numbers

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion # Or LooseVersion, if you prefer

if StrictVersion('10.2.3') > StrictVersion('10.2'):
    print "10.2.3 is newer"
```

Comment: Thanks, and what to do if i need to compare N uniq version numbers ? Does distutils.version has something for this ?

Comment: How do you define comparison for more than 2 items?

Comment: i got it ) . stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
list(map(int, '10.2.3'.split('.'))) > list(map(int, '10.1.30'.split('.')))
Out[216]: True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aknur, will check this as well.